# Single pulse generator

Tags: switches, pulse, low-voltage

For my 10V model train's signals and switches I need a ~500msec power pulse (AC; low Amp).
I already have an electronic switch that provides power when triggered. However, the power should be brief, as the signal's solenoid will otherwise overheat and burn with continues power. I am hoping for a simple circuit design that I create for each signal or switch.
My electronics skills are beginner, but I am good at following instructions.

Comment: Please provide an image of the pulse you wish to generate showing numerically all the important features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-retriggerable monoflop (also called a non-retriggerable monostable multivibrator) to generate pulses with a defined duration.

The [74HC221](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc221.pdf) is a chip that does this. You need to add external timing components (a resistor and capacitor) to set the pulse duration. The circuit diagram and truth table on page 2 of the linked datasheet show how the chip operates, including the aforementioned timing components. Add a 5V power supply (i.e. from a 7805 linear regulator) and a bypass capacitor, and that's it.

There's apparently also a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ8ajVyTBVY) explaining the 74HC221, although I've only skipped over it and not watched it in full.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit gives you about 500ms pulse to selenoid (or relay) after SW is permanently closed:

[image]

Comment: Thx Michal.  This seems doable based on a materials search. Are the bottom 4 inverse T connections to ground and upper left 12V as other supply?  Sorry, but I am a beginner.

Comment: Ya, all bottom is minus pole of power supply (or Gnd if you want). Most upper line is plus pole.

Comment: Also remember with 4k7 and 10k in base of Bjt you are able to drive about 50mA load ( in collector). If selenoid drains more lower these resistor like 1k and 2k2. Also cap has to be higher value like 470uF (to ensure 500ms timing).

Comment: Great.  I will build it and learn, using larger power option.

Comment: I created the circuit in CircuitLab, but cannot upload image to this comment.  What are the connections for solenoid?  Two wires to solenoid switch?  The solenoid goes back and forth with pulse.

Comment: <img src="https://ben.earth.lsa.umich.edu/temp/circuit.png" width="100" height="100">